# simple static method issue

Tags: php

I have a question regarding the abstract class

I have

```
abstract class testMaster
{

    public function __construct($b, $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }

    public static function create($test)
    {
        //handle test
        switch($test) {
         case 'test1':
            require_once 'test1.class';
            return new test1($a, $v);
            break;
         case 'test2':
         case 'test3':
             require_once 'test2.class';
             return new test2($a, $v);
             break;


        }
    }

class tester extends testMaster{

    codes...

}
```

My question is

if I want to call static '`create`' method, how to call it.

I used `testMaster::create()` but it doesn't seem to return anything. Any tips? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this just a typo?  `return new test2($a, $v;` Note missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: It's just a convention but it's useful to have class names with a first capital letter (e.g. TestMaster) to distinguish them from methods.

Comment: "I used testMaster::create() but it doesn't seem to return anything." Also, PHP might be failing gracefully due to the typo mentioned above.

Comment: It's just a typo guys, sorry.

Comment: It won't fail gracefully... it'll be a parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things (see the comments):

```
abstract class testMaster
{

  public function __construct($b, $a)
  {
      $this->a = $a;
      $this->b = $b;
  }

  public static function create($test)
  {

      switch($test) {
       case 'test1':
          require_once 'test1.class';
          return new test1($a, $v);
          break;
       case 'test2':
       case 'test3':
           require_once 'test2.class';
           return new test2($a, $v); // Missing a ')'
           break;


      }
  }

} // Missing '}'

class tester extends testMaster{ // Should be 'extends'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just call `testMaster::create()`, then you're not passing an argument to $test.  Since there's no switch case for $test to be empty, and you haven't declared a `default` case, it just runs to the bottom of Create(), and returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you've fixed the syntax errors, you can call

```
$obj = testMaster::create('test1');
```

By the way, I would definitely suggest you to use some [Class Loader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) mechanism and avoid using require calls.

Furthermore, if you're interested in well-designed testing, you can have a look at [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).